# \dotfill but slightly lowered below line

Tags: vertical-alignment, fill, leaders

I am using `\dotfill` to create space for "fill in the blanks" but I do not like that the dots are exactly on the line. I would like the dots to be slightly below line. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Fill in:\dotfill
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could, perhaps, change the definition of `\dotfill` and `\lower` the dots a little bit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\lowerdotfill{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss\lower0.5ex\hbox{.}\hss}\hfill
  \kern\z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Fill in:\dotfill\par
Fill in:\lowerdotfill
\end{document}
```

or, maybe, use `\dotuline` from the `ulem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
Fill in:\dotfill\par
Fill in:\dotuline{\hfill}
\end{document}
```

here's the output of `\dotfill`, `\lowerdotfill`, and `\dotuline`:

> [image]